# ArcGIS JSAPI: How to select graphic from Graphics layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, select, feature-layer, graphics

In ArcGIS JSAPI there are ways to select Features from FeatureLayer or using querytask like [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/fl_selectfeatures.html) or [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/query_buffer.html) or [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89239/arcgis-javascript-api-select-features). But how to select the Graphic from Graphics Layer?

I am trying to do [this](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/select-features.html) in AGS JSAPI which is accomplished by  **SelectInteraction** in OpenLayers. This lets user select features from map by clicking on them. Base on other interactions of OpenLayers such as (Draw, Modify) AGS JSAPI also provides **toolbar** which let user [Draw](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/draw-amd.html) or [Edit](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/edit-amd.html) Graphics but lacks in selection.

Is there any similar functionality available to JSAPI as well?

Answer (score 1):

Just take the graphiclayer as a normal JS object. All graphic is stored in graphicLayer.graphics as an array. You could use the maps onClick event to locate where exactly the user clicked and use that coord to check which graphic should be selected.

Here's a quick example to show what i meant.

```
map.on("click", function (evt) {
    var g = graphicLayer.graphics;
    for (var loopCnt = 0; loopCnt < g.length; loopCnt++) {
        if((Polygon)(g[loopCnt].geometry).contains(evt.mapPoint)){
            //do whatever you want
        }
    }
});
```